# Visual studio 2010: Can't show design view

Tags: visual-studio-2010, silverlight-4.0, user-controls

I have an problem in Visual Studio 2010:

[image: Visual studio error]

I created an custom user control, that show some data, then I tryed to add it on a page.

When I did this, this error showed up... when I run (start debugging) my application, everything works fine, the only thing that is not working is Visual Studio design view.

What should I do to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your control is displaying data - if it tries to get that data from a remote database (for example) that's not available at design time then this could cause the problem.

You need to either modify your code to cope with the data source being missing (probably a good idea anyway) or wrap the code in a "is this design mode" check.